# Approximate e using small numbers

Tags: code-golf

Given an input integer from 1, 2, ..., n, the task to write code to make a number as close as possible (as measured by absolute distance) to `e` using only the four mathematical operations +, -, *, / and parentheses (brackets). You can use any of the integers up to `n` once but don't have to use all the numbers and you are not allowed to stick digits together to make new numbers for example.

- The input will be  single integer `n` between 1 and 20, inclusive
- The output should be an arithmetic expression which is the closest possible to `e`.

Your code should in principle be correct for `n` all the way up to `20` although of course it doesn't have to terminate in a sensible amount of time. Although not required, it would be great if it did terminate for smaller inputs at least.

## What is e?

```
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995....
```

## Examples

- Input 1. Output 1. Distance \$e - 1 \approx 1.7182818284590451\$.
- Input 2. Output 1+2=3. Distance \$3 - e \approx 0.2817181715409549\$.
- Input 3. Output 3 - 1/2 = 2.5. Distance \$e - 2.5 \approx 0.21828182845904509\$.
- Input 4. Output 2 + 3/4 = 2.75. Distance \$2.75 -e \approx 0.031718171540954909\$.
- Input 5. Output  3+1/(2/5-4) = 2.722222222222.  Distance \$2.722222222222 - e \approx 0.00394039376\$.
- Input 6. Output 2+((6-1/4)/(5+3)) = 2.71875. Distance \$2.71875 - e \approx 0.00046817154\$.

You can take `e` as input to your code if that is helpful.

Comment: I assume that one cannot reuse the same number twice, right?

Comment: @matteo_c *"You can use any of the integers up to n __once__"*

Comment: [Hint](https://oeis.org/A003417)

Comment: The ungolfed version of my code returned `((((1/4)/(3+6))+5)/7)+2` for n=7.

Comment: @user3490 Using a continued fraction certainly helps to _approximate e using small numbers_, but does it really have an application here given the constraint that we're only allowed to use integers 1 to n at most once?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the task? All the answers so far cite the number of bytes of their program, but the way I understand the problem, they should also cite the distance to *e* (as a function of *n*).

Comment: @Stef the requirement is that the absolute distance is optimal so the only thing that differentiates them is the number of bytes.

Comment: On a related note, $$\frac1e\approx\frac{3+8}{5×6}+\frac9{7421}$$

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>280</s> 229 bytes

*-51 bytes thanks to [@AnttiP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84290/anttip)*

```python
lambda n:min(chain(*map(g:=lambda p:["("+l+o+r+")"for i in range(1,len(p))for(l,r,o)in product(g(p[:i]),g(p[i:]),"+-*/")if eval(r)or"/"<o]+[str(p[0]+1)],permutations(range(n)))),key=lambda x:abs(eval(x)-e))
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY9NTsMwEIX3OcXIq5nabUkBgSxykpKF2zqtRfwj20WtKk7Cphs4AnfhANwDNynMwn72PM287_0zHPPOu_NXF70Fq_IOjA0-ZtBV1zx_7HM3ffz-6ZVdbRQ4aY3D9U6Vc2JVwK1srq0glwwZ77nnkTNinY9gwDiIym011qLXDgNR-cdeROGp9EL0m_064xbDUpqWxEUYWQTj08mckelAv6oeI_nI5uzJt3yZciyum5bX1Iqgo91nlY13CcdVjkqJF338i3aQapVwmHOgqSaqBliTdcze9-lKPLnCnrJOea2STtDAqYJStYRaDGoh4XZUtxIWs_tR3130Q3m8VdUALsBf2P8nzcoym5DkYA_RuIyDqWlGwA5NSV2NEc7n8f4F)

Similarly to [@The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu)'s answer, uses brute force and times out for \$n>4\$.

Comment: [Did a little bit of golfing, -51 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY9NTsMwEIX3OcXIq5nabUkBgSxykpKF2zqtRfwj20WtKk7Cphs4AnfhANwDNynMwn72PM287_0zHPPOu_NXF70Fq_IOjA0-ZtBV1zx_7HM3ffz-6ZVdbRQ4aY3D9U6Vc2JVwK1srq0glwwZ77nnkTNinY9gwDiIym011qLXDgNR-cdeROGp9EL0m_064xbDUpqWxEUYWQTj08mckelAv6oeI_nI5uzJt3yZciyum5bX1Iqgo91nlY13CcdVjkqJF338i3aQapVwmHOgqSaqBliTdcze9-lKPLnCnrJOea2STtDAqYJStYRaDGoh4XZUtxIWs_tR3130Q3m8VdUALsBf2P8nzcoym5DkYA_RuIyDqWlGwA5NSV2NEc7n8f4F). I added an explicit check for division by zero and removed the redundant lr-permutation. Also it can now use a subset of the numbers.

Comment: ATO is down :/
I'll update the answer when is back online

Comment: It's back now.....

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES10), 160 bytes

Expects `(n)(e)`. Works up to \$n=5\$ on TIO.

```javascript
n=>g=(e,...a)=>n?g(e,...a,S=m=n--):a.map(p=>a.map(q=>p!=q&&[..."+-*/"].map(o=>g(e,`(${s=p+o+q})`,...a.filter(s=>s!=p&s!=q,(d=eval(s)-e)*d<m&&(m=d*d,S=s))))))&&S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBBbsIwELznFQZVYU1iV0ilh8KmJ3rriSNCwsVOGpTYiZ0iJODtqZOgqrRz8K41uzNjH8RRuL3Nq4ZpI1WbYqsxyRBUzDkXFBP9mt0u8RpL1IzRF8FLUUGFydDUmFQjrMNw48fGEZs@jrc9YbyUX97Bw9lhFZmovtJdr8XTvGiUBYeJG2EV@qOOQaI6igIcZYpO5bIMQyhRTqV3drRHGK7bvdHOFIoXJoOJJheiTpVVzuVGkx4X4lW@VNcoa42d0EVwt8RYxP4i@tfcodMIUmOhUA3RBMls4csSydzXKKLkHBDScV0YT6egKbyL5pOvaBwMuYZUSPpHdnNek5DfyTY67gV4Y9aNzXUGlFdCrrSE2ZzGg4In3/KTkvD0Qz57rjcTHw4GG0Zu7lt@MLmGif@NCfWO1/Yb)

#### Algorithm

We start with the list \$a=[1,2,\dots,n]\$.

For each pair \$(p,q)\in a^2,p\neq q\$ and for each operator \$o\$, we remove \$p\$ and \$q\$ from the list and append a new expression \$(p \oplus o \oplus q)\$.

For each new expression built this way, we compute its squared difference with \$e\$ and update the final output \$S\$ whenever we get a better score.

This process is repeated recursively until all possible expressions have been tried out. (A leaf in the search tree is reached when all elements have been combined into a single expression.)

Because the initial values are not considered as possible answers by this algorithm, we have to set the default answer to \$1\$ for the edge case \$n=1\$.

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                        // outer function taking n
g = (e, ...a) =>            // inner function taking e and an array a[]
n ?                         // if n is not equal to 0 (step #1):
  g(                        //   do a recursive call:
    e,                      //     pass e unchanged
    ...a,                   //     pass all previous entries in a[]
    S = m = n--             //     append n (decremented afterwards)
                            //     NB: S and m are eventually set to 1
  )                         //   end of recursive call
:                           // else (step #2):
  a.map(p => a.map(q =>     //   for each pair (p, q) from a[]:
    p != q &&               //     abort if p = q
    [..."+-*/"].map(o =>    //     otherwise, for each operator o:
      g(                    //       do a recursive call:
        e,                  //         pass e unchanged
        '(' + (             //         append a new expression
          s = p + o + q     //         consisting of s = p + o + q
        ) + ')',            //         surrounded with parentheses
        ...a.filter(s =>    //         filter a[]:
          s != p & s != q,  //           remove p and q
          (d = eval(s) - e) //           d is the difference between
                            //           the evaluation of s and e
          * d < m && (      //           if d² is less than m:
            m = d * d,      //             update m to d²
            S = s           //             and update S to s
          )                 //
        )                   //         end of filter()
      )                     //       end of recursive call
    )                       //     end of inner map()
  ))                        //   end of both outer map()'s
  && S                      //   return the best expression
```

#### Faster ungolfed version

This version can compute \$n=1\$ to \$n=6\$ on TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPBctowFLz7K15ziKXYFjid6aHGmeGQY089MkxHOAKEXdkjC7edhG@n71kmxJA2HCS0Xq1WT/t2spNtYXXjElM/qeNxXVtWKQcGckgznGY5fME5ijg8BwBFbdq6UqKqNyw0eQgRciIIIXkAWuDHTjHDeRYcgmC9N4XTtXmFew3Sn6P@Qggxt1b@wQ9L8VM2jP2IQXPIH2ABGtXSGFg/c@Hq785qs2EcljxGFfqtVOvIKExgesKsahG6SW@yAJGzAyVtsWVzbwFgLvCqjxIhtoBuGoOawvJ0@vOgNSahG5USaTciAeg1uvyUE34GAe8QRmEM4R0NCQ2TEJZnybqJobyQGuRKmME93N7CDv9ofkGgS7q9NdkIPQSjJVVZ/W4sFgOvFkHd4KDS@EIJoJPVXmXjze0v7dBieX1yIVsF069@F2p3pN1hVFZWyTJ7j52O2HcfsO9H7OQD9ucRe/Iv9ju1aYva0rZv0m2FXLXM6yQeeOQXFcFH8TtmPnUvLyeF3AP4WFRuUSmzcVukYRCHxXUVh@D2CtnV21KASeu/dxgCvcCY9c4xXow6sH9z7EgeUlSpxcRaV07Zvrt83kpKqybL5ZDbJX972OHN6hCMMT/3Zl57qq@VzyTZx94/Hv8C)

It has a few improvements over the golfed version:

- don't bother to try both \$a\star b\$ and \$b\star a\$ if \$\star\$ is commutative
- return the shortest expression in case of a tie

Comment: Cool. How long does it take for 6?

Comment: @Simd I've added a link to a faster version that can compute n=6 on TIO.

Comment: Does your method require all the numbers from 1 to n be included?

Comment: @Simd No. Any intermediary expression using less numbers may be selected.

Comment: @Simd The ungolfed version now returns the shortest expression in case of a tie, which forces `3-(1/4)` (without the 2) for n=4.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 121 bytes

```
Ｎθ⊞υＥＮ⟦Ｉ⊕ι⊕ι⟧ＦυＦＬιＦＬι«≔§ικη≔§ιλζ≔§η¹ε≔§ζ¹δ¿∧δ⁻κλＦＥ⟦∕εδ⁻εδ×εδ⁺εδ⟧⟦⪫()⁺⁺§η⁰§/-*+ν§ζ⁰μ⟧⊞υ⊞ＯΦι∧⁻κξ⁻λξμ»≔Συυ≔↔⁻Ｅυ§ι¹θη§§υ⌕η⌊η⁰
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLNTsJAEE682afY9LSrRZFAxHAiGhKMPyQaL4RDaRd2w3YL-0MIxifxwkGjd9_Gp3G2dCtGDt3JzDfzzXwzff1MWKySPBabzbs1k1r7--CpL-fW3NlsTBVekE4wsJphG6HbeI53MRKh4WWsDQQTRTMqDU0xJxD-GxgRIJnkCmFLUGFvqJwa5nL_-c_BYVdrPpW4a_oypSvMIzQDTgYkeyAB0HoPxCJ0BhDdA623UOogPkG4K1OcgjwurcYzR-nncoqHV3zJU4qpq_BZpfPIM1o5A-GBESzmOucSh5iEJVA8O8PVocK74Wnt6BgSJdkJrl2OC2SwP-Rv4Oz9nKrY5Ar3uDBwB9iCk1DNv6rGFM4pONwJXoJyEQ82g1NEyELQ72asc2ENLVmccPs7C3cbg4IFKQ8xUFyaSo63UNHjMAkr-vMM2rCiPQjpvOlxosuf7GMY1pYiHH01Ts7P2o22-5qti3qzFTS3GT8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `e` as the first input and `n` as the second input. Explanation: Brute force, so as usual, times out for `n>4`.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `e`.

```
⊞υＥＮ⟦Ｉ⊕ι⊕ι⟧Ｆυ
```

Start a breadth first search with a list of the initial integers and the expression to generate them (i.e. the value cast to string).

```
ＦＬιＦＬι«≔§ικη≔§ιλζ
```

Loop over each pair of terms from the list.

```
¿∧δ⁻κλＦＥ⟦∕εδ⁻εδ×εδ⁺εδ⟧⟦⪫()⁺⁺§η⁰§/-*+ν§ζ⁰μ⟧
```

If these are different terms and the second term is not zero then loop over the elementary operations on the pair of terms and pair the expressions with the results.

```
⊞υ⊞ＯΦι∧⁻κξ⁻λξμ
```

For each result create a new list with the two terms removed and the new result appended and add this to the lists of lists to be processed.

```
»≔Συυ≔↔⁻Ｅυ§ι¹θη§§υ⌕η⌊η⁰
```

Flatten the final list of lists and output the expression that produces the value closest to `e`.

At a cost of 20 bytes I can avoid performing the addition or multiplication in both directions which speeds the code up a little but not enough to complete `n=5`:

```
Ｎθ⊞υＥＮ⟦Ｉ⊕ι⊕ι⟧ＦυＦＬιＦκ«≔§ικη≔§ιλζＦＥ⁶Ｅη⎇π§⟦∕ξ§ζ¹⁻ξ§ζ¹×ξ§ζ¹⁺ξ§ζ¹∕§ζ¹ξ⁻§ζ¹ξ⟧μ⪫()⪫⎇÷μ⁴⟦§ζ⁰ξ⟧⟦ξ§ζ⁰⟧§/-*+μ¿‹⁰§μ¹⊞υ⊞ＯΦι∧⁻κξ⁻λξμ»≔Συυ≔↔⁻Ｅυ§ι¹θη§§υ⌕η⌊η⁰
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLLTgIxFE3cyVc0s2q16EAGxbgiGhKMKInsCIsBCtMw7UAfBDF-iRsWGt2781P8Gm_nwSMyyaSdc3rPPb1n3r6GUaiGSRiv1x_WjMv136OflpxZ82DFgCk8J9eljtURthS1wxne5QhFvZtQGwCHigkmDRthTgDeB_oERMaJQtgSlK73TE5M5M5m31OCXkrHDa35ROKGackRW2JO0RS0Iig-QMVArRyVCjhrF5nDiKIuUzJUz3hGUVHRu-ULPmJ4uYVWFFWc2TaXVh8iulywg0QnPlyQ99iDKVpuevwj-hQJ2NwlXGIPEy_fFv5b0uSSgqLAjXtHwXcKINDbN-LDuLeAd14-OfVcl-xBfOymrzX2t4dEap-gIme3Ps6YCk2icJPHBrKGiTfkCGf3mO5eKnYf7vbCxfxayqN6sgLipsgCWKQ30ElsDctVXFh264LnQ5yTPPSO4tJsZlasUNHk4CRK-3MBbaK0vQ_t3_VgqPMf-bPnlRex1_-unl1W6tW6e4PalR_USkF24g8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `e` as the first input and `n` as the second input.

At a cost of a further 12 bytes I can add some code that avoids repeated values but I don't know whether this can cause some results to be skipped. It does at least just about work for `n=5` though:

```
Ｎθ⊞υＥＮ⟦Ｉ⊕ι⊕ι⟧ＦυＦＬιＦκ«≔§ικη≔§ιλζＦＥ⁶Ｅη⎇π§⟦∕ξ§ζ¹⁻ξ§ζ¹×ξ§ζ¹⁺ξ§ζ¹∕§ζ¹ξ⁻§ζ¹ξ⟧μ⪫()⪫⎇÷μ⁴⟦§ζ⁰ξ⟧⟦ξ§ζ⁰⟧§/-*+μ¿‹⁰§μ¹¿¬№ＥΣυ§ν¹§μ¹⊞υ⊞ＯΦι∧⁻κξ⁻λξμ»≔Συυ≔↔⁻Ｅυ§ι¹θη§§υ⌕η⌊η⁰
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVNNTwIxEE28ya9o9tRq0YWAYjwRjQlGlERuhMMCxW3YdrEfBDH-Ei8eNHr33_g_vDvd7bqgbLJpO2_mvbfT2eePcRypcRolLy9v1kyrra-d746cW3NtxYgpfE9OKz2rY2wp6kZzvI4RigZnkTYQHCsmmDRsgjmB8GZgSIBkmiqELUHZesXknYldbn6eEfRY2W1rze8kbpuOnLAl5hTNgCuG4i1QAtDKQRmBs3aUO4wp6jMlI_WA5xQVFYNzvuAThpdlaEVRzZntcmn1NqDPBdsK9JLtBV5jI0zR8lfjHzCkSMDmMuUSB5gEflv470jjKQVFDdfuNYbQMQDBYNNICO0uA8FhdW8_cCr5g_jUdV9rHJZJIrOfY9epwWeplSZr6a0VcGdlpvQf-qeSoGJE3HozZyoyqcIXPDEwJnBZbTnBeQtm6_1I3MHxCTchTxV_y4WqhWBx8SOdJtYwz-K82dIG97buiZ-XnuLwBQVcrFBxwcFJnOlzATJxJh-C_KsejbX_B94HQXWRBMPP-sFxrVVvubfRPAkbzUozz_gB) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `e` as the first input and `n` as the second input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 53 bytes

```
hoa.n1.xvNZss.ussmmms.i[\(k\)-db)bs_MB.cd2"+-*/"NtQ]S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyM/US/PUK@izC@quFivtLg4Nze3WC8zOkYjO0ZTNyVJM6k43tdJLznFSElbV0tfya8kMDb4/38TAA)

Uses brute force and times out for \$n>4\$ on TIO. It will prefer short answers given a tie.

#### Explanation

```
hoa.n1.xvNZss.ussmmms.i[\(k\)-db)bs_MB.cd2"+-*/"NtQ]SQ    # implicitly add Q
                                                          # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
                                                   ]SQ    # list [[1... Q]]
             .u                                  tQ       # cumulative reduce lambda N,Y along [0... Q-2] with [[1... Q]] as the starting value
                 m                              N         #   map lambda d over N
                  m                       "+-*/"          #     map lambda k over valid operators "+-*/"
                   m              s_MB.cd2                #       map lambda b over all 2 element combinations from d
                             -db                          #         get the elements in d not in b, [...]
                     .i[\(k\)   )b                        #         interleave ["(", k, ")", [...]] with b
                    s                                     #         reduce on +, first summing into a string, then prepending that string to [...]
               ss                                         #   flatten out unwanted nesting
           ss                                             # flatten out more nesting
 o                                                        # sort this list based on lambda N
  a                                                       #   the absolute difference between
   .n1                                                    #   e
      .xvNZ                                               #   and eval(N) or 0 if error is thrown
h                                                         # take the first element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 331 bytes

```python
def f(x,e):
 d={};A=[*C([*"()",""],x)]
 for o,p,q,r,s in[*product(A,sum([[*permutations(range(1,x+1),n)]for n in range(x+1)],[]),A,C("+-*/",x),A)]:
  try:S="".join("".join(map(str,l))for l in zip(o,p,q,r,s))[:-1];d[S]=eval(S)
  except:0
 return min(d,key=lambda a:abs(d[a]-e))
from itertools import*;C=combinations_with_replacement
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RZGxbtswEIaRVU9BMENJ5ezG6FLI0GB4DJDF3QQioC3KZiMeGeoUyy3yJFm8NK-R50iepnRUN9Pdf-R9vPv5_BIOtPN4fPtxyW492xtWe_xCbK-RWHdA0kPKI1rcdpl1wUf61Odk2tiWTDxLwe0WfTRc_umpmXx_v7ipTcMaMYCRRcbq8vfTfFFW-VJUOReSA-cKBqky1vjIPAR4gAgds1jlIfq635BYQNc7UaWCia4nTdZjJ6LGrREzGK5mElCqUz-mPjYenMoKKiVhAUvBryb5V54egoVUaQ5G8VCsSs6nP71FcY5OB9FRhFbKE6494X7ZIP7PJWVVTGZqXlcrVZpH3YqVTDQzbEyg4jpj0VAfkbkEq-HeHMpWu3WtmS70uhN1pdXESJk10Ttmk3HkfZu2_XA3ny_LjXdri-OKd3tLu7toQqs3xhmk0dPXf3_hNO2yEC2SaMQ3-NDTBB9vHY9j_As)

Brute-force so times out for \$n\ge4\$.

I tried to test it on my computer with \$n=5\$ but it was taking ages (probably because for \$n=5\$ it has to loop through something like 8.8 trillion times), so I can just reassure with the fact that it works *in theory*.